# Hexagon shape with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

Can such a hexagon be created with pure CSS3?

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: On just one element? Don't think so. But if you use more elements you can.

Comment: Not only one. Any amount will be sufficient, if it works :) Couldn't something anything similiar to this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate repeating hexagonal pattern with CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062887/generate-repeating-hexagonal-pattern-with-css3)

Comment: and that awesome linked question by @putvande may be of help as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a hexagon in CSS, symmetry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070719/creating-a-hexagon-in-css-symmetry), [Generate repeating hexagonal pattern with CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10062887), [Hexagonal patten with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14415773), [Creating Hexagons in css / html](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11450967), and tons more. The search feature actually does work.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple search turned this up: [CSS Hexagon Tutorial](http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html)

Referenced from the site:

`Put a 104px × 60px div with a background colour between them and you get (the hexagon):`

```
width: 0;
border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
border-left: 52px solid transparent;
border-right: 52px solid transparent;

width: 104px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #6C6;

width: 0;
border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
border-left: 52px solid transparent;
border-right: 52px solid transparent;
```

Answer (score 31):

You can use the html character `&#x2B22;` (hexagon)...

```css
.hex1::before {
  content: "\2B22";
  color: orange;
  font-size:135px;
}

.hex2::before {
  content: "\2B22";
  display:block;
  color: magenta;
  font-size:135px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<span style="color:blue; font-size:135px;">&#x2B22;</span>
  
<span class="hex1" />
  
<span class="hex2" />
```

Or play with the clipping paths...

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hex3 {
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 5%, 75% 5%, 100% 50%, 75% 95%, 25% 95%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 5%, 75% 5%, 100% 50%, 75% 95%, 25% 95%, 0% 50%);
}
.hex4 {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 95% 25%, 95% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 95% 25%, 95% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex3"></div>

<div class="hex4"></div>
```

Or you can try CSS, using `::before` and `::after` with triangle borders...

```css
.hexagon {
  height: 200px;
  width: 120px;
  background: red;
  position:relative;
  left:50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hexagon::before, .hexagon::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0; 
  top:0;
  /* half height */
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent; 
}
.hexagon::before {
  left:-50px;
  border-right:50px solid red; 
}
.hexagon::after {
  right:-50px;
  border-left:50px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">here is some content inside the hex if you want...</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

in CSS3, everything is possible.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="hexagon hexagon1"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2"></div></div></div>
<div class="hexagon hexagon2"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2"></div></div></div>    
<div class="hexagon dodecagon"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2"></div></div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
BODY
{   background: url(http://placekitten.com/600/600)
}

.hexagon
{   overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hexagon-in1
{   overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon-in2
{   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/240/240);
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon-in2:hover
{   background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/241/241)
}

.hexagon1
{   width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -80px;
}

.hexagon2
{   width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: -80px 0 0 20px;
}

.dodecagon
{   width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: -80px 0 0 20px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/bhGn4/

Answer (score 4):

you can do gradient hexagon by pure html and css.

Here is HTML & CSS Code :

```css
.hexagon-shape {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: transparent;
        /* add slash at the end of line to see the rhombus *
        outline: solid 1px red;/**/
        width: 72.28px;
        height: 72.28px;
        transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866);
    }
    .hexagon-shape:before {
        position: absolute;
        right: 6.7%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 6.7%;
        top: 0;
        transform: scaleY(1.155) skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
        background: linear-gradient(59.82deg, #0976CE 0%, #0976CE 49.36%, #3A91D7 50.11%, #3A91D7 100%);
        content: '';
    }
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-part">
    <div class='hexagon-shape'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I add text inside this hexagon ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this scss-mixin to create a hexagon with a border.
Creates a hexagon in any size or color.

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="hex-holder">
     <div class="hex"></div>
     <div class="hex-content"></div>  (<-- optional) 
</div>
```

1)  simple method:

```
div.hex-holder{
    @import hexagon($width, $color, $rotation, $border, $radius)
}
```

where:

- width = width of your hexagon
- color = border-color
- rotation = rotation
- border = width of border
- radius = border-radius (rounds corners slightly)

  ```
  @mixin($width: 140px $color: black, $rotation: 0, $border: 3px, $radius: 10px){

  $height: $width * tan(60deg) - $border*2 - $radius/2;      
  $naturaldiameter: $width + 2 * cos(60deg);
  position: relative;

  div.hex {
      transform: rotate($rotation + deg);
      width: $width;
      height: $height;
      border-radius: $radius;
      position: relative;
      @include content-box();
      border-top: $border solid $color;
      border-bottom: $border solid $color;
      margin: auto;

      div.hex-content{
          max-width: $height;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 2;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          top: 0;
          transform: rotate(-1*$rotation+deg);
      }
  }

  div.hex::after, div.hex::before{
      content: "";
      margin-top: $border * -1;
      transform: rotate(-60deg);
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      border-top: $border solid $color;
      border-bottom: $border solid $color;
      width: $width;
      height: $height;
      border-radius: $radius;
  }

  div.hex::before{
      transform: rotate(60deg);
  }}
  ```

2) advanced method:
    - this is better if your hexagon changes in size or color.
    it allows you to change only a portion of the properties  (ex. hex_size when screen size changes)

```
div.hex-holder{
    @include hex_basics(30);
    @include hex_color($bordercolor1, $backgroundcolor1);
    @include hex_size($width1, $borderwidth1, $borderradius1);

     &:hover{
        @include hex_color($bordercolor2, $backgroundcolor2);
     }

     @media( query ){
         @include hex_size($width2, $borderwidth2, $borderradius2);
     }
}




@mixin hex_basics($rotation: 0){
    position: relative;

    div.hex{
        transform: rotate($rotation + deg);
        position: relative;
        @include content-box();
        margin: auto;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
    }

    div.hex-content{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        border-radius: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    div.hex::after, div.hex::before{
        content: "";
        transform: rotate(-60deg);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
    }
    div.hex::before{
        transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
}

@mixin hex_size($width: 140px, $border-width: 3px, $radius: 10px){
    $height: $width * tan(60deg) - $border-width *2 - $radius/2;
    $naturaldiameter: $width + 2 * cos(60deg);

    div.hex::after, div.hex::before, div.hex{
        margin-top: $border-width * -1;
        border-top-width: $border-width;
        border-bottom-width: $border-width;
        width: $width;
        height: $height;
        border-radius: $radius;
    }
}

@mixin hex_color($border-color: black, $background-color: white){
    div.hex::after, div.hex::before, div.hex{
        border-top-color: $border-color;
        border-bottom-color: $border-color;
        background-color: $background-color;
    }
}
```

note: `div.hex-content` may not be aligned property, you can set the `top` property to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#hexagon
{   width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

#hexagon:before
{   content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}

#hexagon:after
{   content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```