# Create a transparent hexagon with border in css

Tags: html, css

Already tried this one -
[Hexagon shape with a border/outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418486/css3-hexagon-shape-with-a-border-outline)

**But can't figure out to make it transparent.**
How can I create a hexagon that's transparent and outlined with white border? I'm trying to fiddle with it, but it does not seem to be possible.
I would like to avoid using images.

Comment: also, this can be of help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896791/hexagon-shape-with-css3

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 hexagon shape with a border/outline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418486/css3-hexagon-shape-with-a-border-outline)

Comment: Already tried these codes but can't figure out. How to remove bg and put white border ?

Answer (score 2):

If a SVG is an option, this works:

```css
body {
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon fill="none" points="276.1128234863281,134 213.05642700195312,243.2169189453125 86.94358825683594,243.2169189453125 23.887176513671875,134 86.94358825683594,24.78308868408203 213.05642700195312,24.78308868408203 276.1128234863281,134 " stroke="#fff" stroke-width="15" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Cool. are svg's lighter than css ?

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges when considering weight of SVG vs. CSS. For these purposes, an SVG is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgba` to set a color with transparency. Here's a fiddle with a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/9wqkmvfu/3/.

You can set your own background, and then change the border color to white. I made it black for visibility sake.

**Edit:** It's not directly possible to achieve outline with CSS because of the pseudo elements. I would go with SVG or images in this case.

Comment: thanks man, but I don't want to give any background. I want to make it opaque/transparent?

Comment: What do you mean? Opaque is different from transparent.

Comment: sorry my bad. I want it to appear transparent :) like this -
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/25359/8fdedd41812b7e66b703ec8caf77dfb9