# Is it possible to have an Hexagon Button CSS

Tags: css, button, frontend

I'm trying to create a button that looks like this for my website:
[image]

But I just don't know how to do that in CSS. To make matters worse I can't even find a tutorial on YouTube about this specific design.
Can anyone teach me?

Comment: After checking our favourite search engine: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+hexagon+border&t=chromentp&ia=web, the best one looks to be: https://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html

Comment: @Paul do you have a specific link, I can't find this anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a button with a ::before element, style that ::before element as a hexagon and position it infront of the button.

This is what I've made using the pseudo element ::before, styling it as a hexagon using clip-path.

```css
div.wrapper {
  margin: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a.button {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #883333;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  position: relative;
}

a.button::before {
  z-index: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #ff3333;
  left: -50px;
  top: -18px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="button">FUZIION</a>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/refuziion/pen/OJZXarL)

Comment: Hi please add some code to your answer, otherwise it's better as a comment on the original post.

Comment: can you please provide me a code example. I would appretiate that a lot

Comment: I am writing some right now

Comment: Added the code example, let me know if this helps you @Shend

Comment: yep it's good. I'll just play with the values! Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 2):

Based on this threat [Hexagon shape with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896791/hexagon-shape-with-css3), you can do something like this.

```css
      .hexagon-button {
        width: 300px;
      }
      .button-content {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 20px 70px;
        border-radius: 1em;
        background: rgb(34, 187, 174);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        color: white;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: -1;
      }
      .part1 {
        width: 0;
        border-bottom: 30px solid #6c6;
        border-left: 52px solid transparent;
        border-right: 52px solid transparent;
      }
      .part2 {
        width: 104px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #6c6;
      }
      .part3 {
        width: 0;
        border-top: 30px solid #6c6;
        border-left: 52px solid transparent;
        border-right: 52px solid transparent;
      }
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="hexagon-button">
      <div class="button-content">Register</div>
      <div class="part1"></div>
      <div class="part2"></div>
      <div class="part3"></div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use with `clip-path` and find out clip-path generator on Google or somethings like that

here for you

```css
button {
  background: rgb(58,185,148);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -4.125rem;
  top: -0.5rem;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  background: rgb(58,185,148);
  clip-path: polygon(24% 13%, 50% 0, 76% 13%, 76% 43%, 49% 55%, 24% 44%);
}
```

```html
<button>
  REGISTER
</button>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/bit-bique/pen/jOxrQoM)

Answer (score 0):

CSS is good, but have you considered SVG?

Using external `<a>` (rectangular link)

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg width="28" height="32">
    <polygon points="14,0 28,8 28,24 14,32 0,24 0,8" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

Using internal`<a>` (pixel perfect link)

```html
<svg width="28" height="32">
  <a href="#">
    <polygon points="14,0 28,8 28,24 14,32 0,24 0,8" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Note that you can change the size by adding a `viewBox` and changing the `width` and `height`:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 28 32">
  <a href="#">
    <polygon points="14,0 28,8 28,24 14,32 0,24 0,8" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do it with css. Google "hexagon"

However, it is difficult, unreliable and time consuming. Much easier and more correct to use SVG.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, please add a code example in place of "Google _____"

Comment: @DanCarter, all code examples that make triangles are crutches and I can't recommend them at all. My answer focuses on using SVG instead of CSS perversions.